# Eigenfunctions Laplacian - Bounding the Fourier Coefficients

Tags: laplacian, eigenfunctions

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ be an open set with boundary of class $C^{\infty}$ and let $\{\lambda_{k}\}$ and $\{v_{k}\}$ be the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of -$\Delta$ with Dirichlet condition in $\Omega$, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
-\Delta v_{k} = \lambda_{k} v_k
\end{equation*}
in which $\Delta$ is the Laplacian Operator. We assume that $\{v_{k}\}$ are normalized in $L^{2}(\Omega)$, so that $\{v_{k}\}$ is a Hilbert Basis for $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$, i.e.,
\begin{equation*}
u = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \langle u,v_{k} \rangle v_{k}(x) \ \ \ \ \text{ (in } L^{2} \text{)}
\end{equation*}
for all $u \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and
\begin{equation*}
\langle v_{k},v_{j} \rangle = \begin{cases}
0, & \text{ if } k \neq j \\
1, & \text{ if } k = j
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
in which $\langle u,v \rangle = \int_{\Omega} u(x) v(x) \ dx$ is the inner product of $L^{2}(\Omega)$ (we suppose that $u$ and $v_{k}$ are real-valued functions).

Now, let $u \in C^{1}(\bar{\Omega})$, $u(x) = 0$ for $x \in \partial \Omega$. Show that there exists a constant $C > 0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
\Bigg\lvert \int_{\Omega} u(x) v_{k}(x) \ dx \Bigg\rvert \leq \frac{C}{\lambda_{k}^{1/2}}
\end{equation*}

From First Greens's Identity, for example, we get that
\begin{equation*}
\lambda_{k} \Bigg\lvert \int_{\Omega} u(x) v_{k}(x) \ dx \Bigg\rvert \leq \Bigg\lvert \int_{\Omega} \langle\nabla u(x),\nabla v_{k}(x)\rangle \ dx \Bigg\rvert
\end{equation*}
but I cannot figure out how to proceed from here.

**EDIT:** The result follows by applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
\begin{equation*}
\lambda_{k} \Bigg\lvert \int_{\Omega} u(x) v_{k}(x) \ dx \Bigg\rvert \leq \int_{\Omega} \lvert\langle\nabla u(x),\nabla v_{k}(x)\rangle \rvert\ dx \leq \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u(x)||\nabla v_{k}(x)| dx \leq \lVert (|\nabla u(x)|) \rVert_{L^{2}} \lVert(|\nabla v_{k}(x)|) \rVert_{L^{2}} 
\end{equation*}
and First Green's identity
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\Omega} v_{k}(x) \Delta v_{k}(x) dx = -\int_{\Omega} |\nabla v_{k}(x)|^{2} dx \implies \lVert(|\nabla v_{k}(x)|) \rVert_{L^{2}} = \sqrt{\lambda_{k}}
\end{equation*}
so the result follows taking $C = \lVert (|\nabla u(x)|) \rVert_{L^{2}} < \infty$. Notice the difference between the norm $| \cdot |$ of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and the norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{L^{2}}$ of $L^{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the inequality you have obtained:
$$\begin{equation*}
\lambda_{k} \Bigg\lvert \int_{\Omega} u(x) v_{k}(x) \ dx \Bigg\rvert \leq \Bigg\lvert \int_{\Omega} \nabla u(x) \cdot \nabla v_{k}(x) \ dx \Bigg\rvert
\end{equation*}$$
you can first use Cauchy-Swharz:
$$\lambda_{k} \Bigg\lvert \int_{\Omega} u(x) v_{k}(x) \ dx \Bigg\rvert \leq \|\nabla u\|_{L^2} \|\nabla v_k \|_{L^2}$$
then you can use the crucial property:

> $$\|\nabla v_k\|_{L^2}= \sqrt{\lambda_k}$$

as by Green:
$$\|\nabla v_k\|_{L^2}^2=\int_\Omega \nabla v_k \cdot \nabla v_kdx = -\int_\Omega v_k \nabla\cdot(\nabla v_k)dx= -\int_\Omega v_k \Delta v_kdx=\lambda_k \int_\Omega v_k v_k dx =\lambda_k \|v_k\|_{L^2}^2=\lambda_k$$

So finally:
$$\lambda_{k} \Bigg\lvert \int_{\Omega} u(x) v_{k}(x) \ dx \Bigg\rvert \leq  \sqrt{\lambda_k} \|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$$
which is the expected result (as $u \in C^1$, the quantity $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$ is finite).

Comment: Thanks. I had applied the Cauchy-Swharz ineuqality but have not been able to bound the norm of the gradient of $v_{k}$.

Comment: @marcstyle to bound the norm of the gradient of $v_k$ the idea is to notice that by integration by parts (or Green): $$\int \nabla v_k \nabla v_k = -\int \nabla \cdot (\nabla v_k) v_k=-\int \Delta v_k v_k$$ and $-\delta v_k =\lambda_k v_k$.

Comment: Indeed, but it just seem that it is missing a vector norm. In your answer I believe we have to show that $\lVert (|\nabla v_{k}|) \rVert_{L^{2}} = \sqrt{\lambda_{k}}$, i.e., the $L^{2}$ norm of the gradient vector norm equals the square root of the eigenvalue. In fact,  $\lVert \nabla v_{k} \rVert_{L^{2}}$ does not make sense as $\nabla v_{k}$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ and not a function in $L^{2}$. I have incorporated your answer to my question with this correction.

Comment: By the $L^2$ norm of the vector field I mean:$$\left(\int_\Omega \nabla v_k \cdot \nabla v_k \right)^\frac{1}{2}$$ where $\cdot$ is the inner product of $\mathbb{R}^N$. If you need additional explanations I can edit my answer :-).

Comment: Yeah, I figured, thanks.